# BR replacing issues using regex for new line

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have the following text, which i need to replace, BR tags with \n, so that i get new line.

```
D:\HP\ConfigurationServer_3464\log\nvdmr***.log ~ File not
found<br>D:\HP\DCSSchedulerAgent_3478\logs\HTTPD-DCSSchedulerAgent-3478.log ~
File not found<br>D:\HP\MonitorClient\logs\windowsService.log ~ File not
found<br>D:\HP\PolicyServer_3467\logs\httpd-policyserver-3467.log ~ File not
found<br>D:\HP\ProxyServer_3466\logs\httpd-proxyserver-3466.log ~ File not
found<br>D:\HP\MessagingServer_3461\logs\rms.log ~ file not found<br>
```

Here is the script i have written, but it never got replaced.what i am doing wrong

```
this.downloadData.forEach(x => x.ServiceLogStatus = x.ServiceLogStatus.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg, '\n'));
```

Please see the data:

```
CPUStatus: "1"
Connectivity: "Success"
DiskStatus: "Free Space C: 64.86%↵D: 68.6%↵E: 0%↵F: 0.01%↵G: 56.83%↵H: 80.78%↵I: 80.28%"
HostName: "gtdctiholdb01u"
LastRebootStatus: null
LogTime: "5/15/2019 11:26:01 AM"
MemoryStatus: "Memory Used: 89.86%"
RDPStatus: "05/11/2019 16:50:13"
ServiceLogStatus: " D:\HP\ConfigurationServer_3464\log\nvdmr***.log ~ File not found<br>D:\HP\DCSSchedulerAgent_3478\logs\HTTPD-DCSSchedulerAgent-3478.log ~ File not found<br>D:\HP\MonitorClient\logs\windowsService.log ~ File not found<br>D:\HP\PolicyServer_3467\logs\httpd-policyserver-3467.log ~ File not found<br>D:\HP\ProxyServer_3466\logs\httpd-proxyserver-3466.log ~ File not found<br>D:\HP\MessagingServer_3461\logs\rms.log ~ file not found<br>"
ServiceStatus: ""
SupportDL: ""
```

Comment: Perhaps `ServiceLogStatus` is read-only?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: this.downloadData = this.downloadData.forEach(x => x.ServiceLogStatus = x.ServiceLogStatus.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg, '\n'));

Comment: i am getting above error in console

Comment: Would appear that `this.downloadData` is not defined. Either the code is being called before `downloadData` is defined or `downloadData` is spelled incorrectly (perhaps `downloadedData`?). Please post the code showing how `downloadData` is initially declared and assigned.

Comment: no other fields are replacing fine

Comment: i posted the data in question

Comment: You say that other fields are replacing fine. Please share an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation for the replace regex seems to work just fine. It replaces all `<br>` with newlines:

```js
const str = `D:\HP\ConfigurationServer_3464\log\nvdmr***.log ~ File not
found<br>D:\HP\DCSSchedulerAgent_3478\logs\HTTPD-DCSSchedulerAgent-3478.log ~
File not found<br>D:\HP\MonitorClient\logs\windowsService.log ~ File not
found<br>D:\HP\PolicyServer_3467\logs\httpd-policyserver-3467.log ~ File not
found<br>D:\HP\ProxyServer_3466\logs\httpd-proxyserver-3466.log ~ File not
found<br>D:\HP\MessagingServer_3461\logs\rms.log ~ file not found<br>`;

console.log(str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg, '\n'));
```

Comment: are you saying there is no change required?